# Scramble a Word using Java

Tags: java, shuffle

I wanted to scramble a String, to make it unreadable and so came up with this method:

```
public String scrambleWord(String start_word){

     char[] wordarray = start_word.toCharArray();

        char[] dummywordarray = start_word.toCharArray();

        Random random = new Random();

        int r = random.nextInt(wordarray.length-1);
        int i = 0;

        int j = r+1;

        while(i <= r){

            dummywordarray[wordarray.length -i-1] = wordarray[i];

            i++;
        }


        while (j <= wordarray.length -1){

            dummywordarray[j-r-1] = wordarray[j];

            j++;

        }

        String newword = String.valueOf(dummywa);



        return newword;
```

SO I first converted the string to a char array, and in my method I had to duplicate the char array "dummywordarray". Passing once through this algorithm every lette rof the word will have changed position. But it wont be scrambled very well, in the sense that you could put it back together at a glance.
SO I passed a given String of less than 9 characters through the method 7 times, and the words are fairly well scrambled, i.e. unreadable.
But I tried it with a 30 character string and it took 500 passes before I could guarantee it was nicely scrambled. 500! 
I'm sure there is a better algorithm, I'd like some advice on either
a)improving this method
or
b)a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Nicely Scrambled'

Comment: Do you just want a one way shuffle of the letters, and it will be unrecoverable later? Or do you actually want a cipher to create a reversible shuffle?

Comment: Nicely scrambled is pretty subjective. I'm sorry I cant give you a proper definition. If the original word is troublemaker, then makerelbuort, tromakbleuer are not "nicely scarmbled. You can put them back together after five seconds.

Comment: It is not necessary to reverse it. I just want a nice shuffle that is efficient.

Comment: @JJG: The nature of randomness is that *sometimes* "troublemaker" will be randomly scrambled as "troublemaker".  The ability of the human mind to solve anagrams or jumbles at different stages of "shuffledness" is a much bigger problem that has little to do with programming IMO.

Comment: Thanks Mark Peters. I know that there are outliers where possibly even the original word could come back. But for the bulk of cases, when I put my 30 character phrase (without spaces) into the algorithm, more often than not it was put-back-together-able without much mental effort, unless I go through the above method hundreds of times. I guess it's expected that I would have to run the word through the method many times, but I thought 500+ was pushing reasonable.

Comment: @JJG: In that case Collections.shuffle is a good algorithm.  It pretty much guarantees that every permutation is equally likely.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about

```
ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>(word.length());
for ( char c : word.toCharArray() ) {
   chars.add(c);
}
Collections.shuffle(chars);
char[] shuffled = new char[chars.size()];
for ( int i = 0; i < shuffled.length; i++ ) {
   shuffled[i] = chars.get(i);
}
String shuffledWord = new String(shuffled);
```

In other words, you could take advantage of the existing [`java.util.Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) method.  Unfortunately you have to jump through a couple of hoops to use it, since you can't use primitives in Generics.

### Edit:

The basic way that `shuffle` works (see the Javadoc for the full explanation), is like this:

```
for position = last_index to first_index
   let swap_pos = random number between first_index and position, inclusive
   swap(swap_pos, position)
```

### Edit 2:

This approach is significantly less verbose with Guava's [`Chars`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.html) utilities:

```
List<Character> chars = Chars.asList(word.toCharArray());
Collections.shuffle(chars);
String shuffledWord = new String(Chars.toArray(chars));
```

Comment: Nice and simple.  You could use Arrays.asList(word.toCharArray()) to shorten it further.

Comment: @Adamski: I think that would result in a `List<char[]>` since `Character[]` is not the same as `char[]`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I haven' much experience with Generics, but I'll give it a shot. But do you know the algorithm in the suffle(list) method? I'm just wondering how they do it.

Comment: Can you use `char[] shuffled = chars.ToArray(char[] shuffled)` to remove the second `for` construct?

Comment: @Thomas: No, unfortunately that doesn't compile, again since `char` is not applicable for a generic type parameter.

Comment: @JJG: The link I included points to the Javadoc, which goes into detail about how the shuffle algorithm works.  I'll put a summary in my post.

Comment: Note that this is a Knuth shuffle or Fisher–Yates shuffle.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Randomization

Comment: It seems my algorithm is computationally heavier than it needs ot be, by a big margin. Although the advantage of my shuffle is it allows me to set the degree of "difficulty" of the shuffle (considering shuffling a word, not cards).